# How to call didSelectRowAtIndexPath before prepareForSegue?

Tags: ios

I'm making iOS app which is tableview base.
Here's what I want to do.
Tableview1 -> Tableview2
Once I select one of tableCell, new tableView2 is shown.
I'd like to hilight the cell before new tableView is shown.
Nonetheless, hilight is so slow because of loading new tableView data.
I looked up this. The reason why is `prepareForSegue` is called before `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

Then could you tell me how to call `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` before `prepareForSegue`?

Or tell me how to set up table cell when cell is selected.

All the best.

Answer (score 20):

You are meshing two different ways to do it.

1 - First Alternative - use only storyboards and prepareForSegue:

Connect your prototype cell to the second viewcontroller in storyboard (the connection must start from the cell and end on the second viewcontroller).
In this case, you must use *only* prepareForSegue method and not didSelectRowAtIndexPath. The second VC is pushed automatically after the prepareForSegue.

2 - Second Alternative - use didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

You use didSelectRowAtIndexPath only if you connect the segue *from the first viewcontroller* (and not from the cell) to the second viewcontroller.
At the end of didSelectRowAtIndexPath method, you must call performSegue.

Comment: Thanks! it works, but another problem is occurred.
I'll post new thread about this.

Comment: If you're using the first alternative and need to take action based on the cell's position in the table, use this to get the correct indexPath: NSIndexPath *indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow;

Answer (score 2):

What you need is the following function. It will be called before preparedForSegue. First you need to define a var in you class then set it in this function like bellow:

```
var selectedIndexPath: NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath()

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSIndexPath? {
        selectedIndexPath = indexPath
        return indexPath
    }
```

Then finally you can use this value in preparedForSegue function

Comment: @AadilAli No problem :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Make segue for controller->controler
2. run data loading in didselectrowatindexpath
3. When it done -> perform your segue

Comment: Performsegue is better answer. But another problem is happened.
But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you should setup your view controllers:

1. When the view controller housing Table View 1 loads, load in Table View 1's data.
2. In `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` is called, fire off the segue using `performSegue:`.
3. When the view controller housing Table View 2 loads, load in the data for Table View 2.

It sounds like you might be loading the data for Table View 2 prematurely---which is why you're seeing the lag. Because you're tying up the main thread with your data loading, the UI doesn't have the ability to update and show you the blue highlight.

If you load your data in the `viewDidLoad` method, you'll avoid expensive loads when a user selects a table view cell. You should only tell your view controller to perform the segue to the detail view controller in the `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method.