# From collectionView to Detail

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

Im passing data from one `CollectionViewController` to a detail `ViewController`. Everything seems to be working, but the `"prepareForSegue` is happening before the `"didSelectItemAtIndexPath"` so it's passing the data of the item I selected the last time not the one I'm selecting right now.

This is my **wrong code** for the collectionViewController

```
var cellSelected : Int = 0

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    cellSelected = indexPath.row
    println("Did select!")
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "identifierName" {
        var secondScene = segue.destinationViewController as detailVC

        secondScene.authorDetail = data[cellSelected].userOfImg
        secondScene.likesDetail = data[cellSelected].likesInImg
        secondScene.imageDetail = data[cellSelected].imgPath
        println("Prepare for segue")
    }
}
```

The result in the debug area is:

1. Prepare for segue
2. Did select!

Comment: See [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18165684/1348195) and [that similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13235579/how-to-call-didselectrowatindexpath-before-prepareforsegue) to get an idea.

Comment: Thank you so much @benjamin-gruenbaum, but this examples are using a tableView and for what I've seen in that case I can use the `indexPath.row` inside the `prepareForSegue`. That's why in my code i tried to use the `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Right solution**

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "identifierName" {
        var secondScene = segue.destinationViewController as detailVC
        let cell = sender as UICollectionViewCell
        let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathForCell(cell)
        secondScene.authorDetail = data[indexPath.row].userOfImg
        secondScene.likesDetail = data[indexPath.row].likesInImg
        secondScene.imageDetail = data[indexPath.row].imgPath
        println("Prepare for segue")
    }
}
```

Comment: Works Great! Much more than the patch I had before! Thanks Mihael!

Answer (score 3):

I've found a solution for this. It's to use `shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath` instead of `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`. Doing this the `shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath` will be executed before the `prepareForSegue` and will fix the problem of sending the data of the item you are selecting and not the one selected the last time.

Comment: There is no need to set cellSelected, just use sender in prepareForSegue to get indexPath.